# Error on Installing mobify-client

Tags: node.js, npm, javascript-framework, mobify

I got this error while trying to install mobify client. My node.js version is: 0.8.6 and npm: 1.1.48. Also I am behind a proxy and in first row I just set proxy but I dont know is this act as same as setting http_proxy variable?

```
C:\Users\user>npm config set proxy http://user:pass@proxy:port

C:\Users\user>npm -g install mobify-client
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mobify-client
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mobify-client
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mobify-client
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/mobify-client-0.3.8.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/-/mobify-client-0.3.8.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/mobify-client-0.3.8.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/-/mobify-client-0.3.8.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/mobify-client-0.3.8.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/-/mobify-client-0.3.8.tgz
npm ERR! Error: SSL Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_mo
dules\npm\node_modules\request\main.js:440:26)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:185:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:88:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (http.js:1455:7)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:111:23)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.socketOnData (http.js:1366:20)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.CryptoStream._push (tls.js:485:27)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.cycle (tls.js:839:20)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.CryptoStream.write (tls.js:220:13)
npm ERR!     at Socket.ondata (stream.js:38:26)
npm ERR!     If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "-g" "install" "mobify-client"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\user
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.6
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.48
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there could have been two potential issues here. One is that the npm server may have had some issues at the time, you might want to try again now and see if you get the same error. The same question was asked in our Support forums (may even have been asked by you :) ) and another user said that trying again later fixed the issue:

https://support.mobify.com/customer/portal/questions/445465-installation-error

Another issue is that you may be behind a proxy and can't connect to the npm server. You can set the proxy location using this command:

```
npm config set proxy http://url:port
```

Or if the proxy is authenticated:

```
npm config set proxy http://user:pass@url:port
```

Comment: yes dude I am the one asked this question there too :) I did what you said but the error changed now I updated my post please take a look, thank you

Comment: Hmm strange. I did some quick googling, and one person said that running this command seemed to do the trick: 

`npm config set strict-ssl false`

From here: https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/2663